# kafka-node producer Error: connect ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js, exception, apache-kafka

Recently I picked up a project  base on kafka-node which someone else left .We get the post request,and use kafka producer to send those messages to kafka.When I use Apache Bench to benchmark the code,only 16000 requests sent to kafka and I got the ETIMEDOUT exception. I wonder where the error happened ,kafka node or zookeeper? Please help me to find out what's wrong with my code.
PS:
1. The version of kafka-node is 0.5.6 
2. ulimit -n = 65535 
3. kafkatest() works in router

```
exports.Kafkatest = function(req,res) {
    var TOPIC_UPDATE_TIME = getNowTime(new Date());
    var topicJSON = ‘{“VERSION”:VERSION,“PRODUCT_LINE”:PRODUCT_LINE,“COMPONENT”:APP,“OPR_TYPE”:OPR_TYPE,“TOPIC_UPDATE_TIME”:TOPIC_UPDATE_TIME,“SRC”:APPSPACE,“PURPOSE”:PURPOSE}’;
    var args = eval(’(’+topicJSON+’)’);  //topic's message

    var post = '';
   req.on('data', function(chunk) {
        post += chunk;
    });
   req.on('end',function() {
        args["DATA"] = url.parse(post,false).query;    //get data from post
        args["HEADERS"] = req.headers;                 //use post's HEADER
        const HighLevelProducer = kafka.HighLevelProducer;
        const client = new kafka.Client(KAFKA_PORT,0);       //KAFKA+PORT = zookeeper:2181
        const producer = new HighLevelProducer(client, {
                requireAcks:1
        });
        var playloads = [{ topic: SAMPLE_TOPIC, messages:[JSON.stringify(args)], partition: 0}];    topic
        producer.on('ready',function(){
                producer.send(playloads,function(err) {
                        if(err) {
                                console.log('【' + new Date() + '】' + "ERROR!");
                                console.log(err);
                                client.close();
                                producer.close();
                        }else {
                                console.log('【' + new Date() + '】' + 'JSON was sent to kafka !!!');
                                client.close();
                                producer.close();
                        }
                });
        });

        producer.on('error',function(err) {
                console.log(err);
                client.close();
                producer.close();
        });
        res.end();
        res.destroy();
});}
```

codes in router:

```
router.post('/post', function(req, res){
        transfer.kafkatest(req,res);
        res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type':'text/plain'});
        res.write('Recived!');
        res.end();});
```

Pictures:
Apache Bench
[image]

Exceptions
[image]